# Unable to RDP into my Azure VM because of inbound rule?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I recently installed Norton Antivirus on my Azure VM. As soon as I did, I lost my RDP connection. Now I'm not able to RDP into my VM. I saw this message in my portal:

[image]

So I took a look at my inbound rules and saw the following:

[image]

I'm not exactly sure how to read this. Is the **DenyAllInBound** rule preventing me from connecting to my VM? If so, I didn't add this. Something added it and I cannot remove it. Can someone suggest what I need to do to fix this connection issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem and seen you post this. I just fixed mine and thought it might help you as well. I was trying all types of different things but Going into your RDP Rule try changing the source port range to something different. When I changed mine to a * instead of putting numbers it actually worked and I was able to get in. Took me forever to figure that out. However I am running a linux Vm with ubuntu.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30947248)

Answer (score 2):

The deny all rule is not something you can remove. It is also the highest rated rule which means it will be applied after all other rules. So looking at your NSG configuration you do have it setup correctly.

Seeing as you had access to your VM and after installing Norton you do not, it is safe to assume Norton is the issue. From past experience it is likely that Norton modified the firewall rules inside the VM which is not blocking traffic.

Start with this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-rdp-connection

It goes over the basic steps to start troubleshooting RDP issues.

If Norton is the cause, you will likely want to look into this doc which uses serial console to correct the RDP keys inside the VM

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-rdp-general-error